# How to design the return type of getData()?

Tags: c++, templates

```cpp
#include <variant> 
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

enum class typeFlag {
kFloat32 = 0,
kFloat64 = 1,
kUint8 = 2
};

class NDArray;

template<typename T>
class TBlob{
    friend class NDArray;
    public:
        TBlob(): dptr_(nullptr) {};
        TBlob(size_t size): dptr_(new T[size]) {};
        ~TBlob(){if (dptr_) delete [] dptr_;}
    private:
        T *dptr_;
};

using datahandle = std::variant<TBlob<float> *,      \
                                TBlob<double> *,     \
                                TBlob<uint8_t> * >;

class NDArray{
    public:
        NDArray(): dtype_(typeFlag::kFloat32) {}
        NDArray(size_t size, typeFlag dtype): dtype_(dtype) {alloc(size);}
        ~NDArray() {if (&data_) delete &data_;}
        void alloc(size_t size){
            switch(dtype_){
                case typeFlag::kFloat32:
                    data_ = new TBlob<float>(size);
                    break;
                case typeFlag::kFloat64:
                    data_ = new TBlob<double>(size);
                    break;
                case typeFlag::kUint8:
                    data_ = new TBlob<uint8_t>(size);
                    break;
                default:
                    data_ = new TBlob<float>(size);
                    break;
            }
        }
        const auto getData() {
            if (dtype_ == typeFlag::kFloat32) return std::get<0>(data_)->dptr_;
            else if (dtype_ == typeFlag::kFloat64) return std::get<1>(data_)->dptr_;
            else return std::get<2>(data_)->dptr_;
        } 
    private:
        typeFlag dtype_;
        datahandle data_;
};

int main(){
    NDArray a(5,typeFlag::kUint8);
    std::cout << a.getData()[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Got Error:

```cpp
prog.cc: In member function 'const auto NDArray::getData()':
prog.cc:52:79: error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: 'float* const' and then 'double* const'
             else if (dtype_ == typeFlag::kFloat64) return std::get<1>(data_)->dptr_;
                                                                               ^~~~~
prog.cc:53:45: error: inconsistent deduction for auto return type: 'float* const' and then 'unsigned char* const'
             else return std::get<2>(data_)->dptr_;
                                             ^~~~~
```

Seems that the `getData()` function always return a `float *` type according to the default value of `dtype_`, which is `float`.

How can I make it possible to return different type according to the run-time value of `dtype_`? I need to process the pointer returned by `getData()` and those operations is unrelated to the type of this pointer. For example:

```cpp
NDArray NDArray::operator*(const float scalar) const{
    NDArray ret(*this);
    for (size_t i=0; i<ret.getSize(); i++){
        ret.getData()[i] *= scalar;
    }
    return ret;
}

// Many other operations...
```

If I template `getData()`, does it means that I must template `operator*` too? It will make things ugly and I want to avoid it.

If you have better idea, plz help me!

Comment: Afaik C++ has no runtime polymorphism. Function return type must be known at compile time. But it can be a `std::variant<float, double, uint8>`

Comment: @JHBonarius ?! Of course it does. It *famously* does. For example virtual function inheritance, and also via other means (one of which is even used in OP’s code, namely `std::variant`).

Comment: @konradrudolph but that's static polymorphism isn't it. Known at compile time. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @JHBonarius No, that’s 100% dynamic and it’s resolved at runtime. Static polymorphism would be overloading or templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A single non-template function (or class member) cannot have a return type dependent on some runtime value (`dtype_` in your case), that's the core of the error. The compiler tries to deduce a single return type and fails, since different code paths return `float *`, `double *` and `uint8_t *`.
2. It isn't true that your operations don't depend on the type of the pointer. In this single line `ret.getData()[i] *= scalar` you already need to know the type, for proper indexing (the `[i]` part) and proper multiplication (the `*=` part).

There are many options for what you could do here. I would suggest to make `NDArray` a template itself that would hold a data pointer & a size, without any type flags. This would make things much simpler & future-proof (e.g. nothing breaks if you decide that you also need to store `uint16_t`).

If, however, you absolutely must have this 3-type layout with runtime deduction of the type, you could do roughly the following. Add an `apply` function that will take any callable object and call it with an appropriate data type, e.g.

```
class NDArray {
    ...
    template <typename F>
    void apply(F f) {
        if (dtype_ == typeFlag::kFloat32)
            f(std::get<0>(data_)->dptr_, getSize());
        else if (dtype_ == typeFlag::kFloat64)
            f(std::get<1>(data_)->dptr_, getSize());
        else
            f(std::get<2>(data_)->dptr_, getSize());
    }
    ...
};
```

and then use it in your `operator *` with a template lambda:

```
NDArray NDArray::operator*(const float scalar) const{
    NDArray ret(*this);
    ret.apply([](auto * data, size_t size){
        for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++){
            data[i] *= scalar;
        }
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Note that this `apply` copies the callable for simplicity, but it should rather accept a forwarding reference and do proper forwarding, like

```
template <typename F>
void apply(F && f) {
   ...
   std::forward<F>(f)(std::get<0>(data_)->dptr_, getSize());
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail response! I want my ```NDArray``` to be type-erased, so that I don't want it templated and I make ```TBlob``` templated instead.

Comment: @欧岳枫 Note that the `apply` function itself it templated here, `NDArray` isn't. So it's still type-erased. It's just that the user must pass in a function which can process the type that's actually stored in your `NDArray` object. Which he must know, because how else is he going to pass in the correct function? Also see the example using `overloaded` here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit.

Comment: @Darhuuk That's cool! Thank you(Darhuuk&lisyarus) for your inspiring answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this from a single function, since the return type is not part of a function's signature. I.e. `int foo ();` and `double foo ();` are the same function, so can't exist at the same time.

Since your code is using a variant internally already, you could design your access functions to work similar to `std::variant`. E.g. make the accessor a template:

```
template <typeFlag Type>
auto const & getData () {
  if constexpr (Type == typeFlag::kFloat32) { return std::get<0>(data_)->dptr_; }
  else if constexpr (Type == typeFlag::kFloat64) { return std::get<1>(data_)->dptr_; }
  else { return std::get<2>(data_)->dptr_; }
}
```

Of course, this requires the caller to know which template argument to use for `getData()`. The answer by lisyarus shows a nice way to implement vistor-like behavior instead, which does not require this.

Some extra remarks:

- The `dtype_` enum is kind of redundant. All necessary type information is already contained within `data_`. You can get it out using e.g. `std::holds_variant<TBlob<float> *>(data_)`.
- You're using raw pointers, which IMHO is just asking for problems. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead. That will take care of all potential memory leaks and make your `NDArray` uncopyable.
- You should follow the rule of 5: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three. You're currently going to be either leaking memory all over the place or calling delete on already deleted pointers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice about memory stuff! I will be careful about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would template `data_` and remove `dtype_`:

```
template <typename TData>
class NDArray
{
    public:
        ...
        const TData getData() { return std::get<0>(data_)->dptr_; }

    private:
        TData data_;
}
```

Then, when you construct it, pass the type in the template, not as an argument:

```
int main()
{
    NDArray<uint8_t> a(5);
}
```

If you need to make construction of NDArray dynamic, create a function and use a similar `switch` to the one you have in `alloc()` but returning `NDArray` object:

```
switch(dtype_)
{
    case typeFlag::kFloat32: return NDArray<float>(size);
    case typeFlag::kFloat64: return NDArray<double>(size);
    case typeFlag::kUint8:   return NDArray<uint8_t>(size);
    default:                 return NDArray<float>(size);
}
```

Comment: `NDArray` is probably supposed to be type erased so that won’t work. And what would the return type of your `alloc` function even be?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, I want my ```NDArray``` to be  type erased, so that I don't want it templated and I make ```TBlob``` templated instead.